# Grep process using initctl

Tags: bash, process, operating-system, init

Below is my `initctl` script. with this i am trying to bring up a process when system comes up. 
The problem is, `initctl` is giving me job failed status though my process is up and running.

if i do `ps -aef | grep process_name`, will it work?
If so, how can i do ps after executing DAEMON.

```
console output
respawn
env DAEMON="./BRINGUP"
env PKILL="pkill BRINGUP"


pre-start script
su -s /bin/sh -c "$DAEMON" 12345
end script

pre-stop script
/bin/sh -c "$PKILL"
end script

script
sleepWhileAppIsUp(){
  while pidof $1 >/dev/null; do
  sleep 1
     done
}
sleepWhileAppIsUp $DAEMON
end script
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Which OS and version?

Comment: linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64

Comment: "Linux" and the kernel's version isn't very informative -- different distros have different conventions and different versions of the pertinent tools.  So, which distro and which version of that distro?

Comment: `pidof process_name` is much better than `ps | grep` even if you take care to craft a regex which doesn't match itself.

Comment: What is supposed to do is, to produce the status after checking whether the process is running or not.  Here After doing su -s /bin/sh -c "$DAEMOM", how can i use ps???